# How can i add new item to existing data using jquery

Tags: jquery

In my application i am doing Jquery autocomplete textbox here when i enter values into textbox i need to add with comma separated value  to existing datasource

```
 getDataSource: function getDataSource() {
            var $input = this.$element;
            var inputVal = $.trim($input.val());//this is new item
            var dataSource = this.options.dataSource;
     var dataSource = this.options.dataSource.append(',',inputVal); //here I am getting Exception 

            if (this.props.isFirstGetDataSource) {
                var objDataSource = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < dataSource.length; i++) {
                    for (var key in dataSource[i]) {
                        this.options.dataSource[i][key] = String(dataSource[i][key]);
                    }
                }
                this.props.isFirstGetDataSource = false;
                for (var _i2 = 0; _i2 < dataSource.length; _i2++) {
                    objDataSource[dataSource[_i2][this.options.id]] = dataSource[_i2];
                }
                this.props.objDataSource = objDataSource;
            }
            return this.options.dataSource;
        }
```

here i am  using http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Dynamic-Autocomplete-Multi-select-Plugin-With-jQuery-magicsearch/multiple.html for jquery autocomplete textbox for adding multiple items here when i type not exists data i am able to display No Result found but instead of this i am displaying typing new data but when i select it it's shows in textbox (generally,normally new data is not accepts textbox and search box is hide) but here the problem i am unable to select next data it's not separate with comma how can i do this

Comment: You mean you want the script to auto fill the text box while the user is typing values in to the textbox?

Comment: @Sand, Here when i type something new item textbox accepts but after when i type another data it accepts also like new but it's not taken separated with comma